# How to get default value of java datatype using generic method?

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm writing a program and need to get the default value of datatype (for example null for List, 0 for int, false for boolean, etc...). I have this method

```java
private static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> type) {
    if (!type.isPrimitive()) return null;
    // something should go there
}
```

and I don't know how to recognize the type and return the value without errors.
I tried `if (type.equals(Integer.class)) return new Integer(0);` but I get an error for the return statement `Required type: T, Provided: Integer`.

How can I do that and is there any other method than mine? (I don't want the method to return `Object` ofc)

Thanks!

Comment: primitive types are not reference types, but generic types can only *hold* reference types (one reason for wrapper types)

Comment: Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: @user16320675 i know, thats why i'm asking, If user used `Integer.class` as input the output will be `new Integer(0)`. But I don't know how to do that. I edited the question so now it's clear

Comment: Note that `Integer` is not a primitive type, so it would already return `null` according to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check each primitive type manually (there are not so many primitives in Java):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T defaultValue(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (!clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            return null;
        }
        if (clazz == int.class) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(0);
        } else if (clazz == long.class) {
            return (T) Long.valueOf(0);
        } else if (clazz == float.class) {
            return (T) Float.valueOf(0);
        } else if (clazz == double.class) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf(0);
        } else if (clazz == char.class) {
            return (T) Character.valueOf('\0');
        } else if (clazz == byte.class) {
            return (T) Byte.valueOf((byte) 0);
        } else if (clazz == short.class) {
            return (T) Short.valueOf((short) 0);
        } else if (clazz == boolean.class) {
            return (T) Boolean.valueOf(false);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported primitive type: " + clazz);
        }
    }
```

To test you can use:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List.of(String.class, int.class, long.class, double.class, float.class, boolean.class, byte.class, char.class).forEach(
                cls -> System.out.printf("%s - %s\n", cls.getName(), defaultValue(cls))
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think you should extend your solution to support Wrapper-classes to.
Like so: `if(!clazz.isPrimitive() && !Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)`
And in the checks would be extended like the following : `if(clazz == int.clazz || clazz == Integer.class)`

Comment: @Max.-F. it depends on expected behavior: the default type for `Integer` is `null` but for `int` is `0`, so if user wants to get default values for wrapper classes to be the same as for origin primitives, then it could be extended with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kirill's solution, I'd like to add some background reasoning.

Your approach is correct, you only need an additional `(T)` cast:

```
private static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> type) {
    if (!type.isPrimitive()) return null;
    if (type.equals(Integer.class)) return (T) (new Integer(0));
    // and so on for the other primitive types
}
```

This `(T)` cast will earn you a warning, as the compiler can't infer that it's in fact safe.

By writing the `(T)` cast, you as the developer guarantee that in this case (being called with `Integer.class`) the `new Integer(0)` instance is of the requested type `T`, and that's correct, as with the argument being `Integer.class`, `T` can only be `Integer`.

You need not even consider superclass/subclass situations, as you specified an exact type `<T>`, not `<? super T>` or `<? extends T>`, so you can be sure that the class object received as argument exactly matches the generic type `T` (unless you ignore errors/warnings elsewhere).